# Javascript save data to sessionstorage everytime page or view is rendered

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, storage

How can we retain the data stored in a sessionstorage everytime a page or view or even script is rendered ? even you navigate back and forth on the browser ?. I have a feature in my program where in everytime the view is rendered it saves a data to the sessionstorage but when i navigate back it just contain the current data that is saved. I want to have access to all the data that is saved to the session storage and not just the current one. Any solution?. Ihave tried local storage , same thing ?>

## Code

```
var urls_list = []
        urls_list.push(locals.data.phone.phone_url)
        sessionStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(urls_list));
        result = sessionStorage.getItem('result');
```

## local storage

```
var urls_list = []
            urls_list.push(locals.data.vehicle.vehicle_url)
            localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(urls_list));
            result = localStorage.getItem('result');
```

Answer (score 1):

The sessionStorage object stores data for only one session (the data is deleted when the browser tab is closed).

Tip: Also look at the localStorage property which stores data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

Try This:

```
<div id="demo"></div>

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  localStorage.setItem("name", "Smith");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("name");
} else {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

Comment: So you mean if i navigate back the session local storage is lost ?>